# Archiving hourly files with different names

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log file which looks like this:

```
2018/10/08 12:15:04 David access denied
2018/10/08 12:15:05 David access denied
2018/10/08 12:15:05 David access granted
2018/10/08 13:15:14 Karel Jan access granted
2018/10/08 13:15:19 Lydia access denied
2018/10/08 13:15:20 Lydia access denied
2018/10/08 13:15:21 Lydia access granted
2018/10/08 14:15:26 Henk access denied
2018/10/08 14:15:26 Henk access denied
2018/10/08 14:15:27 Henk access denied
```

Script:

```
file="log.txt"
while read -r regel
do
        sort | awk '{file=$1 substr($2,1,2); gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",file) }
                {print > ("logfile_" file ".txt")}'
        zip logfile_20181008.zip logfile_20181008{00..23}.txt   
done < "$file"
```

This is what I got so far with help, also getting the errors below:

```
ArchiveerLog.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
ArchiveerLog.sh: line 6: `  {print > (prefix bestand".txt")}'
```

I have hourly logfiles, and want to zip them for each day so the zip would be called logfile_20181008.zip as above, is there a way to NOT hardcore this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you want to sort it? How do you want to archive it? Is this log file a stream of data / are these logs appended to a file? Are empty newlines part of the log file?

Comment: Tried to read out the timestamps to compare them but unsuccesfull. Sort the file by the hour, and archive by day. Newlines was a mistake from copy paste so fixed that.

Comment: @David please include the code you've tried in your question then

Comment: Added what I saved, I have deleted what I had apperently, since nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an unsorted log-file with a log-key of this type, you are a bit in an uneasy position. Sortable date-time formats are of the form `YYYY[c]MM[c]DD[c]hh[c]mm[c]ss[.sss]` and are always represented in the same Time zone. The format you present is not directly sortable by means of a simple ascii ordering. As a simple example. The keys "01/01/2018.00:00:00" < "01/10/2018.00:00:00" <  "10/10/1302.00:00:00".

Using the tool `sort` you can set up a complicated sorting structure:

```
sort -k1.7n,1.10 -k1.4n,1.5 -k1.1n,1.2 -k1.11 <logfile>
```

This will sort your file correctly. Now you can pipe this into [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to do the splitting by hour :

```
sort -k1.7n,1.10 -k1.4n,1.5 -k1.1n,1.2 -k1.11 <logfile> \
    | awk -v prefix="logfile_" '{file=substr($1,1,13); gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",file) }
                                {print > (prefix file".txt")}'
```

This will sort the file and move all lines to the files `logfile_DDMMYYYYhh.txt`

**Update**: After the question has been updated!

```
sort log.txt \
 | awk '{file=$1 substr($2,1,2); gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",file) }
        {print > ("bestand_" file ".txt")}'
```

**Second update:** so your entire script can now be written as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#######################################################
# THIS IS NOT TESTED BUT SHOULD BE UPDATED WHERE NEEDED
#######################################################

# This is your input
logfile="log.txt"

# create a temporary directory where to do all the work
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

# get the full path of logfile
logfile=$(readlink -f "$logfile")

cd "$tmpdir" || exit
sort "$logfile" | awk '{file=$1 substr($2,1,2); gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",file) }
                       {print > ("logfile_" file ".txt")}'

# Now you have a $tmpdir with lots of files
# perform the zipping
oldstring=""
newstring=""
for files in ./*; do
   #remove last 6 characters ("hh.txt")
   newstring="${files%[0-9][0-9].txt}"
   [[ "${newstring}" == "${oldstring}" ]] && continue
   zip "$(dirname $logfile)/${newstring}.zip" ${newstring}[0-9][0-9].txt
   oldstring="${newstring}"
done

# uncomment this part only if you are sure it works
# # cleanup
# cd $(dirname $logfile)
# rm -rf "$tmpdir"
```

Comment: When I add this piece of code (after changing my date format to ASCII (2018/09/08 12:37:42 David access granted)) the sort method gives an error:

ArchiveerLog.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
ArchiveerLog.sh: line 6: ` | awk -v prefix="bestand_" '{file=substr($1,1,13); gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",file) }'

Comment: @DavidMertens the code works on the original case. If you change the date time key, you can just use sort without any options

Comment: @DavidMertens we also don't know what this error means as we do not see your script. Maybe update your original question with what you have so far.

Comment: Updated it above

Comment: @DavidMertens your single quote is in the wrong place (so was mine, I have updated my answer now to have the correct quote (after the last `}`)

Comment: The output is only 1 file named logfile_20181008.txt. Not separate files for the different hours.

Comment: That is because you changed the format, initially you had the format "DD/MM/YYYY.hh:mm:ss" now it is "YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss" (notice the space). I'll update this!

Comment: When i removed the "<logfile> \" part it works as intended! Thanks alot!

Comment: Updated above, for the zipping part.

Comment: Thanks for this update. Recieved an error for the zippin part:

zip warning: name not matched: [0-9][0-9].txt
zip error: Nothing to do! (/home/david/Desktop/DeepDiveLinux/./logfile_2018100812.txt.zip)
 zip warning: name not matched: [0-9][0-9].txt

Comment: @DavidMertens the script is updated with the fix (typographical). I hope this script is now doing what it should.

Comment: When I remove the "[0-9][0-9].txt" part at the end it works for the zips the invidual hourly files but doesn't put them in 1 zip (for the same date).
When I leave the code same error occurs:
zip error: Nothing to do! (/home/david/Desktop/DeepDiveLinux/./logfile_2018100812.txt.zip)
 zip warning: name not matched: ./logfile_2018100813.txt[0-9][0-9].txt

Seems like it doens't remove the last 6 characters cause the zip files are named: logfile_2018100914.txt.zip

Comment: @DavidMertens and yet another fix `${newstring#[0-9][0-9].txt}` -> `${newstring%[0-9][0-9].txt}`